# Read line for each file c#

Tags: c#

How can I read line by line for a list of files? 
I have a directory with a number of files, I need to save all the files in a list and process them one by one, line by line.

So far I have done the following :

```
//fetching all files from directory
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("path");
Dictionary<int, FileInfo> DatFiles = new Dictionary<int, FileInfo>();
int filecounter = 1;


foreach (var dat in d.EnumerateFiles())
{
    DatFiles.Add(filecounter, dat);
    filecounter++;
}
    Console.WriteLine(filecounter);
foreach (var fileName in DatFiles)
{

   foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName.Value.OpenText().ToString()))
   {
      //run some methods
   }
}
```

When executing, I'm getting an exception, file not found. Even though the list is full of file names.

Comment: Are they all text files or of arbitrary type?

Comment: What exact problems are you experiencing with your above code?

Comment: To get a list of files you were getting close with DirectoryInfo, now call the [GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) method. To read text content from a file do some reading about [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnumerateFiles()` returns a list of `FileInfo` objects, and `File.ReadLines()` takes a `string` path argument;  you probably want to use `File.ReadLines(fileName.Value.FullName)` in your `foreach` as that gives the path to the actual file;  `OpenText()` returns a `StreamReader` object.

Comment: @Paparazzi If he just needs the lines of the file, there's no reason to manage the StreamReader object and go through all of that; let the framework handle it.  This way seems more concise for his use case, plus it remains in the style he was presenting.

Comment: All of that?  He already has a FileInfo and a call to OpenText().  He has gone through the overhead of creating the FileInfo.  Why start over?  FileReadLines has to read in all lines before it starts enumerating.

Comment: @Paparazzi well OpenText was not working in my method and whenI used FullName I was able to start streaming line by line for every file in that list

Comment: @WT86 Glad you got it working.  It would work fine.  You have FileInfo and StreamReader is very good at line by line.  If you used the syntax in my answer it would have worked fine.

Comment: @Paparazzi The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient. [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Kateract I am not talking about ReadAllLines.  If you already have a reference to FileInfo then OpenText is going to be slightly more efficient than starting over.  What you proposed works fine.  And worked for the OP.  Good answer.

Comment: @Paparazzi I disagree that it would be more efficient, as the next step is to open a file stream, which does not already exist as part of the FileInfo object. I'm not 100% sure, but I would assume the overhead for creating the stream is the same for either of our methods. If you really feel the need to make this snippet more efficient, then the real next step would be to suggest OP use `Directory.GetFiles()` as MoustafaS suggested to eliminate the creation of the `DirectoryInfo`, `FileInfo`, and `Dictionary` objects.

Comment: @Kateract Dude, ReadLines use StreamReader.   If you already have FileInfo you already have a reference to the file.   I am going to assume he got the FileInfo for a reason.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/ReadLinesIterator.cs

Answer (score 0):

This smaller code should do the task

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("path");
foreach(var f in files)
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(f))
    {
       var lines = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine});
//    Do here
     }

}
```

Comment: OP has a FileInfo so why not use that.  Why read in all lines and split when there is a ReadLine method?

Comment: This or ReadLine, what I thought he wanted was all, but ofcoure he can read line by line

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails refer to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Open the stream and read it back.
using (StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText())
{
    string s = "";
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```